# how to get parameter in a Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities: `LevelActivity`, `GameActivity` and a `popupwindow`. Now, when user clicks on the level in the `LevelActivity`, it goes in to the `GameActivity`, then after the level is completed, `popupwindow` is called and calls the `GameActivity` again for the continuous flow of the level. In between, if the user press back, it goes to `LevelActivity` where now I am facing the problem. My `GameAcitivity` selects the level depending on the `popupWindow`'s `Bundle` data passed. But now I am facing issue when user press back and it comes to `LevelActivity`?

How to get the same parameters for an activity from two different Activities ?

Comment: use a staic class and set these paramters ther instead of passing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Application class to store level globally.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private int level;


    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //initalization code when app starts

    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
    public void setlevel(intlevel) {
        this.level = level;
    }
```

can set and retrieve from application class like this:

```
 MyApplication myApp  = (MyApplication)MyApplication.getContext();

myApp.setLevel() and myApp.getLevel()
```

check this link to more about application class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: make the methods static and you won't need to instantiate `myApp`